# SQLPlus settings to generate tab-separated data file

Tags: oracle, tabs, sqlplus

Anyone have a good set of sqlplus configuration directives to help transform a given sql query into nicely tab separated output for pulling into a spreadsheet or further processing?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Check out the Oracle documentation:

- [Formatting SQLPlus Reports](http://68.142.116.68/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081008)
- [Generating HTML Reports from SQLPlus](http://68.142.116.68/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch7.htm#sthref1452)

You can generate a tab in Oracle by using the tab's ASCII value 9 and the chr function:

```
select chr(9) from dual;
```

Comment: links are broken and they don't provide a useful concise answer. Consider describing the solution and providing links as an additional reference.

Answer (score 9):

As Justin pointed out in his link, using the `set colsep` function SQLPlus command saves typing a separator for each column.

But for tab-delimited, `set colsep Chr(9)` won't work.

For UNIX or LINUX, use `set colsep '   '` with the space between the single-quotes being a typed tab.

For Windows, use these settings:

```
col TAB# new_value TAB NOPRINT
select chr(9) TAB# from dual;
set colsep "&TAB"

select * from table;
```

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0, `set colsep ' '` typed tab works for me.

Answer (score 3):

One particular script that I have stolen on more than one occasion comes from an AskTom thread on [extracting data to a flat file](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:68212348056#74643125201557).  If I needed a quick and dirty flat file out of SQL*Plus.  I would tend to prefer the DUMP_CSV function Tom posted earlier on that thread for any sort of ongoing process, though.

Answer (score 1):

I got a stupid solution. It worked very well.

## Solution

```
SELECT column1 || CHR(9) || column2 || CHR(9) || column3 ... ...
FROM table
```

## principle behind

Actually, it's just a **string concatenation**.

CHR(9) **->** '\t'

column1 || CHR(9) || column2 **->**  **concat(column1, '\t', column2)**

Comment: Warning: doing this will truncate your output for the line as soon as a newline character is encountered in one of the values.

Comment: @Marvin W: How would you do this if you had a query like this in your sqlplus: SELECT * from table; I would like to select all columns in my table, separate them by tabulator and end each dataset (line) with chr(13)||chr(10). How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Tab characters are invisible, but, if you type the following:-

set colsep Z

but instead of the Z, press the TAB key one your keyboard, followed by enter, it works.  SQLPlus understands that the next character after the space (the invisible tab) is the colsep.

I've placed all my settings into a file named /cli.sql so I just do this:-

@/cli.sql

to load them all.

```
set serveroutput on
SET NEWPAGE NONE
set feedback off
set echo off
set feedback off
set heading off
set colsep  
set pagesize 0 
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 32767
connect use/password
```

(BEWARE - there is an invisible tab after an invisible space on the end of the line:)

```
set colsep
```

Enjoy!