# Output key, value pairs with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, key-value

I am using sqlplus to output the content of a table :

```
select * from my_table;
```

The output is similar to this :

```
ID
-------------
FIELD1
----------------
FIELD2
----------------
someid
field 1 content
field 2 content
```

I tried many combinations of the page formatting options. I can format the output in a table by setting `head`, `pages`, `termout`, `echo`, `feed` and `linesize`.

But I would like to output the values in a (key, value) fashion, like this :

```
ID = someid
FIELD1 = field 1 content
FIELD2 = field 2 content
```

Delimiter and formatting is not important, as long as I have one column per line.

Is it possible using only sqlplus ? I would like to avoid scripting this. On this particular machine (an appliance I can't install anythin on) I only have bash, perl and Python 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any SQLPlus settings that will get you this format, but can do it by brute force. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  'ID = ' || id || CHR(10) ||
  'FIELD1 = ' || field1 || CHR(10) ||
  'FIELD2 = ' || field2
FROM my_table
```

---

**Addendum** OP asked if it's possible to make `CHR(10)` the `COLSEP` value in SQLPlus. I initially thought "no way", but stumbled across [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066859/2091410) on how to set the `COLSEP` to a tab, and modified it to do `CHR(10)`. I don't quite understand how/why it works, but it does work:

```
col NEWLINE# new_value NEWLINE NOPRINT
select chr(10) NEWLINE# from dual;
set colsep "&NEWLINE"
```

Comment: Works great, thanks ! Any chance the `CHR(10)` be set with `set colsep` ?

Comment: I didn't know this, but it turns out it can - please see my updated answer.